# Avoid firing mouseover event if cursor is already inside element?

Tags: jquery

I've got this `div` that runs a little animation whenever you mouse over it:

```
$('.cg-panel').bind('mouseover.anim', function() {
    $(this).stop(true).css({ 'opacity': 0.4 }).transition({ 'opacity': 0 }, 800);
});
```

The problem is that `.cg-panel` sits on top of another `div` that is shown and hidden as it's needed:

```
$('#control_grid').show();
```

When the "control grid" is shown the mouse-over event immediately fires. I don't want it to fire if you mouse is already over-top of it, only when your mouse enters it from the side.

How can I avoid firing that first event?

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJfc9/6/) -- try in chrome. it's locking up firefox for some reason, not sure why.

[I can't bind the event after it's shown either](http://jsfiddle.net/rJfc9/7/)

Comment: If you are only wanting it to occur when you first enter the div, why dont you use mousenter?

Comment: @JoshMein: I tried both. Same behaviour.

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle so we can see exactly what you are doing?

Answer (score 2):

It is kind of hard to test this theory without your html and a better description of what you are wanting; however, since you only want the event to occur when fist entering the div, is there a reason you don't want to use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`?

```
$('.cg-panel').bind('mouseenter.anim', function() {
    $(this).stop(true).css({ 'opacity': 0.4 }).transition({ 'opacity': 0 }, 800);
});
```

Also as a note, depending on what version of jquery you are using, [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is deprecated and has been replaced by [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('.cg-panel').on('mouseenter.anim', function() {
    $(this).stop(true).css({ 'opacity': 0.4 }).transition({ 'opacity': 0 }, 800);
});
```

**Edit**:

I tweeked your demo a little bit, and I came up with [this possible solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rJfc9/12/).

Comment: Yes, because that has the exact same behaviour. It's triggered when it's shown.

Comment: here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rJfc9/3/ i don't recommend running it in firefox..seems extra sketchy and locks up my browser for it. try it in chrome. put your mouse in the box right away, then wait for it to turn yellow. the event doesn't fire right away, but as soon as you move your mouse a pixel.

Comment: I see what you mean, but when are you wanting to show this div? What exactly are you trying to achieve? It seems like there is an easier way, but that may just be because I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've got a gallery of images. When you click one the image zooms in, and there's an invisible grid of actions overlayed for going to the next or previous image. When you mouse over one of the grid tiles it flashes an icon showing you what it will do when you click it. I bind the animations to the grid immediately and hide the grid until you open an image. Soon as you open an image one of the tiles will flash immediately...it doesn't look good.

Comment: I came up with a possible solution and added the jsfiddle to my answer. Let me know if it will work with your actual code. You definitely have an interesting problem here. I am going to keep looking into this.

Comment: Trying to figure out how I can integrate this... I don't have a "c" in my scenario, and I don't think I can add a "c" because I've got stuff behind there (the gallery), and I need to be able to click-through.

Comment: Is there a particular piece of the gallery that might do for c?

Comment: No. I think "c" has to align perfectly with "b" for that solution to work correctly. I think I found another workaround though..posting in a sec.

Comment: @Mark If you know the position that your popup div is going to be, you can still use mousemove and check the current mouse location and whether it is where the div would show.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could manually do some coordinate detection and check which panel it will fall in to. That's a lot of work for something so simple though.

Answer (score 0):

The "control grid" is displayed inside an onclick event. If I set a variable at the same time,

```
$cg.show().data('flash', false);
```

Then I can use that to prevent the first "flash":

```
$('.cg-panel').on('mouseenter.anim', function() {
    if($cg.data('flash')) {
        $(this).stop(true).css({ 'opacity': 0.4 }).transition({ 'opacity': 0 }, 800);
    } else {
        $cg.data('flash', true);
    }
});
```

This only works because my grid covers the entire screen, so it's impossible for your mouse to NOT be over-top one of the panels when it appears. (Unless maybe I add keyboard events.....which is a plan...but, I don't have a better solution)